# what does he think about the French Revolution

Tags: word-usage, word-order

*When, in 1953, Chou En Lai, the Chinese Prime Minister, was in Geneva for the peace negotiations to end the Korean war, a French journalist asked him what does he think about the French Revolution; Chou replied: "It is still too early to tell."*

Source: http://www.lacan.com/zizrobes.htm

Is the word order ("what does he think") OK? Would it not be better "what he thinks". Or is this a sort of Zizek's intentional approach to English (the same as he does in the case of his accent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What he thinks*—a 'fused relative clause'—is the correct construction; but it is still incorrect. The clause should be cast in the past tense, both to reflect its context syntactic context and to reflect the current status of its subject:

> ... a French journalist asked him ***what he thought*** about the French revolution.